# Close responsive menu after click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which opens and closes a responsive menu (#burger-nav) on toggle click of an icon (#burger). Menu options jump to anchors in the same HTML page, but the menu stays open.

How can I also close the responsive menu on click of an option, so that when the user returns to the top of the page, the menu is closed in its original state?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// ----- Responsive menu -----

    ( function( $ ) {
     /* Run this code when the #mob-nav-toggle link has been tapped or clicked */
     $( '#burger' ).on( 'touchstart click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var $body = $( 'body' ),
          $page = $( '#wrapper' ),
          $menu = $( '#burger-nav' ),

          /* Cross browser support for CSS "transition end" event */
          transitionEnd = 'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd';

      /* When the toggle menu link is clicked, animation starts */
      $body.addClass( 'animating' );

      /* Determine the direction of the animation and add the correct direction class depending on whether the menu was already visible. */
      if ( $body.hasClass( 'menu-visible' ) ) {
       $body.addClass( 'up' );
      } else {
       $body.addClass( 'down' );
      }

      /* When the animation (technically a CSS transition) has finished, remove all animating classes and either add or remove the "menu-visible" class depending whether it was visible or not previously. */
      $page.on( transitionEnd, function() {
       $body
        .removeClass( 'animating down up' )
        .toggleClass( 'menu-visible' );

       $page.off( transitionEnd );
      } );
     } );
    } )( jQuery );
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>            
        <nav id="burger-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" title="">parent link</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#bookmark" title="">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#bookmark" title="">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#bookmark" title="">link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#bookmark" title="">link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="" title="">parent link</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">parent link</a></li>
                <li><a href="" title="">parent link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

Comment: post the html  !!

Comment: please add you plunker code

Comment: @bRIMOs - done :)

Comment: cant figure out wher is the matter ! please could you create a working example in a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Answer (score 0):

Change your anonymous event handler function to a named function:
You can then call it when you click the hamburger button or a menu item link

```
(function ($) {

        function menuToggle(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $body = $('body'),
                        $page = $('#wrapper'),
                        $menu = $('#burger-nav'),
                        /* Cross browser support for CSS "transition end" event */
                        transitionEnd = 'transitionend webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd';

                /* When the toggle menu link is clicked, animation starts */
                $body.addClass('animating');

                /* Determine the direction of the animation and add the correct direction class depending on whether the menu was already visible. */
                if ($body.hasClass('menu-visible')) {
                        $body.addClass('up');
                } else {
                        $body.addClass('down');
                }

                /* When the animation (technically a CSS transition) has finished, remove all animating classes and either add or remove the "menu-visible" class depending whether it was visible or not previously. */
                $page.on(transitionEnd, function () {
                        $body
                                .removeClass('animating down up')
                                .toggleClass('menu-visible');

                        $page.off(transitionEnd);
                });

                $(document).ready(function () {
                        // ----- Responsive menu -----
                        /* Run this code when the #mob-nav-toggle link has been tapped or clicked */
                        $('#burger').on('touchstart click', menuToggle);
                        $('#burger-nav').on('touchstart click', 'a', menuToggle);

                });
        }}
)(jQuery);
```

Comment: Where do those 2 snippets of code go?  
I cant get your solution working?  
  
The javascript is held inside a functions.js file referenced in the HTML head, with the html snippet obviously in-page.

Where do your two snippets need to be placed?
And nothing to change in the HTML to work with your code?

Comment: Sorry, I introduce a couple of syntax errors, I have now edited my answer

Comment: i replaced my javascript snippet above with yours above, but it still doenst work? Am I missing something? (no html changes btw)

Comment: possibly, it turned out that your original js had a syntactical error, but my answer was based on the assumption that it worked

Comment: so have you had it working at your end mate? I cant get it to here :(